# Block records unless all records in partition would be blocked

Tags: sql, algorithm

Basic problem description:
A large table with data, some of which is invalid (mostly "by design" due to a prior loss of resolution).
A smaller table that lists valid combinations on a subset of fields from the big table.
A process that sometimes has "real" invalid data - entries that the small table thinks are invalid, but were "used" (in this case, the document was mailed) due to either bad config or corrupt data in the mail file.

The goal - block invalid entries over a partition (a client-doc combo) but do not block any entries on the partition if it would leave the partition with 0 entries.  Basically - if all of them are bad, shrug and assume they are all good enough.

The primitive answer:
Join large and small table (filtering join), distinct on partition.  Left join result and small table to large table, write condition that either small table entry exists (good line) or distinct sub-query entry does not exist (no valid entries), otherwise exclude.

Drawback - Final input, large table X2, small table X2. Large table is self-joined on the partition, which rather painful from an algorithm run time perspective.

So - the question: is there a better algorithm?

**Edit for Jim** - to talk about an abstract algorithim in concrete terms:

Table A - large, contains the data, has a partition, call it "Part"
Table B - smaller, contains validation data.  Key is all fields, call it "Filt"

```
select A.*  
from A  
left join B on A.Filt = B.Filt  
left join (select A.Part from A join B on A.Filt = B.Filt ) C on A.Part = C.Part  
where B.Filt is not null or C.Part is null
```

Can anyone produce the same results with a better query?  (Or, frankly, any different query.)

I'm implimenting in MS Access, hence the "is null" and avoiding "existing" (keyword) sub-queries - I beleive that impliments the same algorithim with different syntax, though anyone that knows better is welcome to correct that theory.

Comment: Please be a little more obscure in your problem description, 'cause I think there are a few bits of it that aren't totally confusing. You'll need considerably more detail and a lot less meaningless jargon if you want anybody to understand your question and provide a helpful answer.

Comment: So, we've got sql (psuedo) code now, hopefully that helps.  Can't say I'm all too clear where the jargon was lurking, but then, I've a known tendency to write a bit like (bad) Hemmingway - fewest wrods => fewest chances to misunderstand, right?  Ironicly enough, the new try at discribing it is even denser, but hopefully people like it more.  If the reason why I'm trying to do this isn't clear, the first discription losely covers it.